# How can I extend the firebase test mode read/write rules beyond 30 days?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm working on a small project that isn't too serious so I'm not going to implement any real rules to its realtime database, but I'll need a bit more than 30 days for the test mode to be running.

My question is, what's the date format on these rules used below by Firebase?

```
{
  "rules": {
".read": "now < 1638392400000",  // 2021-12-2
".write": "now < 1638392400000",  // 2021-12-2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `1638392400000` value is just an [Unix epoch timestamp](https://www.epochconverter.com/clock) in milliseconds.

> The Unix epoch (or Unix time or POSIX time or Unix timestamp) is the
> number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 (midnight
> UTC/GMT), not counting leap seconds (in ISO 8601:
> 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).

---

You can use an online converter like https://www.epochconverter.com/ to generate a new Timestamp value and adapt your rules with this value.

For example, `2021-12-2` will give a Timestamp of `1638403200000` and therefore your rules should be changed to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "now < 1638403200000", 
    ".write": "now < 1638403200000",  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for.